# k consecutive integers constraint

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, gurobi

How can I state the following constraint in Constraint Programming? (Preferably in Gurobi or Comet).

S is an array of integers of size n. The set of integers that I can use to fill the array are in the range 1-k. There is a constraint ***ci*** for each of the integers that can be used. ***ci*** denotes the minimum number of consecutive integers *i*.

For example if c1 = 3, c2 = 2 then 1112211112111 is not a valid sequence since there must be two consecutive 2's, whereas 1112211122111 is a valid sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using the regular constraint (automaton in Comet) would be the best approach.

However, here is a straightforward solution in MiniZinc which use a lot of reifications. It should be possible to translate it to Comet at least (I don't think Gurobi support reifications).

The decision variables (the sequences) are in the array "x". It also use a helper array ("starts") which contains the start positions of each sequences; this makes it easier to reason about the sequences in "x". The number of sequences is in "z" (e.g. for optimization problems).

Depending on the size of x and other constraints, one can probably add more (redundant) constraints on how many sequences there can be etc. This is not done here, though.

Here's the model: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/k_consecutive_integers.mzn

It's also shown below.

```
int: n;
int: k;

% number of consecutive integers for each integer 1..k
array[1..k] of int: c;

% decision variables
array[1..n] of var 1..k: x;

% starts[i] = 1 ->  x[i] starts a new sequence
% starts[i] = 0 ->  x[i] is in a sequence
array[1..n] of var 0..k: starts;
% sum of sequences
var 1..n: z = sum([bool2int(starts[i] > 0) | i in 1..n]);

solve :: int_search(x, first_fail, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;

constraint
   forall(a in 1..n, b in 1..k) (
      (starts[a] = b ) -> 
         (
             forall(d in 0..c[b]-1) (x[a+d] = b )
             /\
             forall(d in 1..c[b]-1) (starts[a+d] = 0 )
             /\
             (if a > 1 then x[a-1] != b else true endif)    % before 
             /\
             (if a <= n-c[b] then x[a+c[b]] != b else true endif) % after
         )
  )
  /\
  % more on starts
  starts[1] > 0 /\
  forall(i in 2..n) (
     starts[i] > 0 <-> ( x[i]!=x[i-1] )
  )
  /\
  forall(i in 1..n) (
     starts[i] > 0 -> x[i] = starts[i]
  )
;

output [ 
     "z     : " ++ show(z) ++ "\n" ++
     "starts: " ++ show(starts) ++ "\n" ++
     "x     : " ++ show(x)  ++ "\n"
];


%
% data
%

%% From the question above:
%% It's a unique solution.
n = 13;
k = 2;
c = [3,2];
```